# ASP.NET CSHTML - "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'user'."

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql, razor, webmatrix

I'm trying to learn how to use CSHTML and .NET to do a simple db connection and query output to a website but I'm having hours of problems, from my connection string to the actual query I've had trouble. Please help me locate the problem and get this basic query to work.

Database=Microsft SQL Express
schema= id (int), user ( nchar(10) ), password (char(32) ).

**Contents of Web.Config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>
   <connectionStrings>
   <add name="MyConnectionString"
     connectionString="Data Source=LAPTOP\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=databasename;Integrated Security=False;User ID=sa;Password=password" />        
</connectionStrings>
<system.web>
   <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

And below is my failed attempt at a query. I tried to use the examples from w3 schools http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/webpages_database.asp to no avail.

**Contents of ListProducts.cshtml**

```
@{
var connectionString = "Data Source=LAPTOP\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=databasename;    Integrated Security=True";
var providerName = "System.Data.SqlClient";
var db = Database.OpenConnectionString(connectionString, providerName);
var selectQueryString = "SELECT * from user";
}
<html> 
<body> 
<h1>Test</h1> 
<table> 
<tr>
<th>id</th> 
<th>username</th> 
<th>password</th> 
</tr>
@foreach(var row in db.Query(selectQueryString))
{
<tr> 
<td>@row.id</td> 
<td>@row.user</td> 
<td>@row.password</td> 
</tr> 
}
</table> 
</body> 
</html>
```

And every time I run I get this error

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'user'.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'user'.

Source Error:


Line 14: <th>password</th> 
Line 15: </tr>
Line 16: @foreach(var row in db.Query(selectQueryString))
Line 17: {
Line 18: <tr>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try enclosing `user` in square brackets:

```
var selectQueryString = "SELECT * from [user]";
```

`user` is [a reserved word](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) in SQL.

Comment: I'll be darned, that did the trick too. I now hate user and all it stands for.

Comment: @Jon I posted the answer before trying to find a link for the fact, which I'm not 100% sure then. Edited my answer for more certainty ;)

Answer (score 0):

Guessing the issue is related to the database (Initial Catalog).

```
Data Source=LAPTOP\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=databasename
```

Is your database really named "databasename"?

Comment: the error “Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'user'.” makes me think it's not related to that particular part though

Comment: I'm starting to think this has more to do with the data-types i am retrieving, I selected a different table and this worked fine

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it must have been something related to my database. I had a table called user with a column also called user. I renamed the table user to users, updated the code and now it all works fine!